# PowerBI user cannot access Built In Serverless DB on Azure Synapse

Tags: sql-server, azure-active-directory, azure-synapse

We have an issue with a particular user connecting to our Serverless SQL pool via PowerBI.

I created an Azure Synapse workspace, which contains the built in serverless SQL pool which has some Views set up to pull data from some Parquet files.

As the creator of the DB I can connect to the SQL pool no problem and can model the data from the views in powerBI. However when my colleague attempts to do the same he can see the names of the views/tables but gets the following error:

He is an admin on the synapse workspace, and I've even explicitly given his user account access to the parquet files but nothing seems to make a difference.

He is able to access a dedicated SQL pool on the same account with no issues

[image]

Comment: Azure Synapse and Apache Synapse are *very* different products; please do ensure you tag appropriately.

Comment: apologies, clearly i clicked the wrong link on the tag auto-complete thing. i am aware they are different and I am looking for help on Azure Synapse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the directions here [Tutorial: Create Logical Data Warehouse with serverless SQL pool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/tutorial-logical-data-warehouse#access-and-permissions)

In particular for the user you need to `GRANT REFERENCES ON DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL`.  If you give the user access to the credential, they won't need direct access to the Data Lake.